Page number of text on word document using Win32com
I am trying to write a python script that reads a word document and will return the page number that specific text is found on. I am able to find the text but am unsure how to get the page number within the same loop (or at all). I am pretty new to COM objects in general so any information would be super helpful. Thanks in advance!
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(file_path)
    for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
        text = paragraph.Range.Find.Execute(FindText="Sample Text")


Hint: If you have a question about Word (or Excel) COM model, it's worth it to look for a VBA solution, as VBA is what people use most often when they need to access Word (Excel) object model. Once you know what to do, you may implement it in the language of your choice.
Word document is not normally split into pages. Page counting occurs on the fly if the info is needed for printing or to refresh page numbers. A call to Repaginate will make Word to refresh page count.
Disclaimer: the code below was not tested with Python.
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdbuiltinproperty
WD_PROPERTY_PAGES = 14
doc.Repaginate()
page_count_property = doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(WD_PROPERTY_PAGES)
page_count = page_count_property.Value

